# Cart gets empty on failed payment response from strip in onestepcheckout magento2

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento2, onepage-checkout

I have implemented stripe in onepagecheckout in magento2 its working fine. But when getting error in response from stripe e.g: 'insuffcient funds, cvv incorrect , expiry date' etc cart gets empty.

Already tried with changing version of magento but didinot work.

Tried to catch or debug error in Failure.php in below module file but didnot work
/var/www/html/durovinbathrooms/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage/Failure.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.